# Inferring a random walk from noisy "images"

Tags: bayesian, hidden-markov-model, kalman-filter, particle-filter, filter

I'm interested in the following inference / filtering problem in a hidden Markov model setting. Suppose we have a simple random walk $x_t\in\mathbb{Z}$ and observations are "images" consisting of iid pixels $y_{n,t}$ of the form

$$
y_{n,t} \sim \mathcal{N}(\epsilon\delta_{n,x_t},1)
$$

where $\delta_{j,k}$ is a Kronecker delta and  $\epsilon$ represents the signal to noise that gives the "visibility" of the trajectory in the image i.e. the size of the spike at $x_n$ relative to the background noise.

As usual, filtering corresponds to finding the posterior distribution $p(x_T|y_{1:N,1:T})$ conditional on the "images" or "movie" $y_{1:N,1:T}$. It is straightforward to set up inference by the [forward algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_algorithm), but I'd like to know if there are any results about this setting, which seems quite natural. Unlike a Kalman filter, the observations are nonlinear. Just for illustration, here's a simple numerical experiment show a random walk trajectory $x_t$, the measurements $y_{n,t}$, and the posterior $p(x_T|y_{1:N,1:T})$. Although the path is barely visible in the image $y_{n,t}$ it is easily inferred

[image: Path is barely visible in image but easily inferred]

**My question is:** has the inference problem been studied before, and if so, what is known about it?

Comment: Pixels in an image are unlikely to be iid. What is $\delta$?

Comment: It's a Kronecker delta. The "image" interpretation is that this spike represents the path of a particle, which is corrupted by pixel noise